# How do you align labels and entry boxes in a GUI program?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple GUI program with Python, but I am having trouble aligning the labels of my program so that the first letter of each word lines up with one another. I tried to use `anchor="nw"` and `anchor="w"`, but these did not seem to do the trick. I am also having a hard time getting the entry boxes to align with each other. My code as well as the expected GUI are attached. If anyone has suggestions, please let me know.

```
import tkinter

class Loan:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create main Window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Loan Calculator")

        #Create the six frames
        self.intRate_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.numYears_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.loanAmount_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.monthlyPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.totalPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # Create and pack the widgets for interest rate
        self.intRate_label = tkinter.Label(self.intRate_frame, \
                text='Annual Interest Rate', anchor="w")
        self.intRate_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.intRate_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.intRate_label.pack(side='left')
        self.intRate_entry.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for number of years
        self.numYears_label = tkinter.Label(self.numYears_frame, \
                text='Number of Years', anchor = "w")
        self.numYears_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.numYears_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.numYears_label.pack(side='left')
        self.numYears_entry.pack(side='left')


        #Create and pack the widgets for loan Amount
        self.loanAmount_label = tkinter.Label(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                text='Loan Amount', anchor = "nw")
        self.loanAmount_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.loanAmount_label.pack(side='left')
        self.loanAmount_entry.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for monthly payment
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                text='Monthly Payment', anchor="w")
        self.monthlyPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.monthlyPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.monthlyPayment)
        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.monthlyPayment_label.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for total payment
        self.result2_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                text='Total Payment', anchor="w")
        self.totalPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.totalPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.totalPayment)
        self.result2_label.pack(side='left')
        self.totalPayment_label.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for the button widgets
        self.compute_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                             text='Compute Payment', command=self.calc)
        self.compute_button.pack(side='left')

        self.intRate_frame.pack()
        self.numYears_frame.pack()
        self.loanAmount_frame.pack()
        self.monthlyPayment_frame.pack()
        self.totalPayment_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc(self):
        #Get 
        self.intRate = float(self.intRate_entry.get())
        self.numYears = float(self.numYears_entry.get())
        self.loanAmount = float(self.loanAmount_entry.get())
        #Calculations
        monthlyIntRate = self.intRate / 1200   
        monthlyPayment = self.loanAmount * monthlyIntRate/(1 - (1 / (1 +     [enter image description here][1]monthlyIntRate) ** (self.numYears * 12))) 
        totalPayment = self.monthlyPayment * self.numYears * 12 #calculates the total payment

        self.monthlyPayment.set(self.monthlyPayment)
        self.totalPayment.set(self.totalPayment)


loan1 = Loan()
```

Expected GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem originates from the frames you used: they are never packed. So pack them and set this option: `fill='both'`.

You also did mistakes when, sometimes, you pack two widgets of the same frame to `left` instead of setting one of them to the `left` and the other to the `right`.

You also need to use the `justify='right'` for the text to show in the right inside each entry widget.

Here is your code (need to be cleaned) with the demo:

```
import tkinter

class Loan:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create main Window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Loan Calculator")

        #Create the six frames
        self.intRate_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.intRate_frame.pack()
        self.numYears_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.numYears_frame.pack(fill='both')
        self.loanAmount_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.loanAmount_frame.pack(fill='both')
        self.monthlyPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.monthlyPayment_frame.pack(fill='both')
        self.totalPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.totalPayment_frame.pack(fill='both')
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame.pack(fill='both')

        # Create and pack the widgets for interest rate
        self.intRate_label = tkinter.Label(self.intRate_frame, \
                text='Annual Interest Rate',  anchor="w")
        self.intRate_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.intRate_frame, \
                                 width=20, justify='right')

        self.intRate_label.pack(side='left')
        self.intRate_entry.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for number of years
        self.numYears_label = tkinter.Label(self.numYears_frame, text='Number of Years')
        self.numYears_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.numYears_frame, justify='right')
        self.numYears_label.pack(side='left')
        self.numYears_entry.pack(side='right')


        #Create and pack the widgets for loan Amount
        self.loanAmount_label = tkinter.Label(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                text='Loan Amount', anchor = "nw")
        self.loanAmount_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                                 width=20, justify='right')
        self.loanAmount_label.pack(side='left')
        self.loanAmount_entry.pack(side='right')

        #Create and pack the widgets for monthly payment
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                text='Monthly Payment', anchor="w")
        self.monthlyPayment = tkinter.StringVar() 
        self.monthlyPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.monthlyPayment)
        self.result_label.pack(side='left')
        self.monthlyPayment_label.pack(side='right')

        #Create and pack the widgets for total payment
        self.result2_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                text='Total Payment', anchor="w")
        self.totalPayment = tkinter.StringVar() 
        self.totalPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.totalPayment)
        self.result2_label.pack(side='left')
        self.totalPayment_label.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack the widgets for the button widgets
        self.compute_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                             text='Compute Payment', command=self.calc)
        self.compute_button.pack(side='right')

        self.intRate_frame.pack()
        self.numYears_frame.pack()
        self.loanAmount_frame.pack()
        self.monthlyPayment_frame.pack()
        self.totalPayment_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc(self):
        #Get 
        self.intRate = float(self.intRate_entry.get())
        self.numYears = float(self.numYears_entry.get())
        self.loanAmount = float(self.loanAmount_entry.get())
        #Calculations
        monthlyIntRate = self.intRate / 1200   
        monthlyPayment = self.loanAmount * monthlyIntRate/(1 - (1 / (1 +     monthlyIntRate) ** (self.numYears * 12))) 
        totalPayment = self.monthlyPayment * self.numYears * 12 #calculates the total payment

        self.monthlyPayment.set(self.monthlyPayment)
        self.totalPayment.set(self.totalPayment)


loan1 = Loan()
```

Demo (on Ubuntu):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try packing the frames, or not using them. frames are used to group widgets together. you can also use "anchor" with "side"

```
import tkinter

class Loan:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create main Window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Loan Calculator")

        #make a frame for alignment
        self.entry_frame =  tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.entry_frame.pack(side="right", anchor="n")

        # Create and pack the widgets for interest rate
        self.intRate_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                text='Annual Interest Rate', anchor="w")
        self.intRate_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.entry_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.intRate_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.intRate_entry.pack(side="top", anchor="w", pady=1)

        #Create and pack the widgets for number of years
        self.numYears_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                text='Number of Years', anchor = "w")
        self.numYears_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.entry_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.numYears_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.numYears_entry.pack(side="top", anchor="w",  pady=1)


        #Create and pack the widgets for loan Amount
        self.loanAmount_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                text='Loan Amount', anchor = "nw")
        self.loanAmount_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.entry_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.loanAmount_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.loanAmount_entry.pack(side="top", anchor="w", pady=1)

        #pack the frame
        #self.entry_frame.pack(side="top", anchor="e")

        #Create and pack the widgets for monthly payment
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                text='Monthly Payment', anchor="w")
        self.monthlyPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.monthlyPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                            textvariable=self.monthlyPayment)
        self.result_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.monthlyPayment_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

        #Create and pack the widgets for total payment
        self.result2_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                text='Total Payment', anchor="w")
        self.totalPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.totalPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, \
                            textvariable=self.totalPayment)
        self.result2_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.totalPayment_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

        #Create and pack the widgets for the button widgets
        self.compute_button = tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
                             text='Compute Payment', command=self.calc)
        self.compute_button.pack(side="top")

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc(self):
        #Get 
        self.intRate = float(self.intRate_entry.get())
        self.numYears = float(self.numYears_entry.get())
        self.loanAmount = float(self.loanAmount_entry.get())
        #Calculations
        monthlyIntRate = self.intRate / 1200   
        monthlyPayment = self.loanAmount * monthlyIntRate/(1 - (1 / (1) ** (self.numYears * 12))) 
        totalPayment = self.monthlyPayment * self.numYears * 12 #calculates the total payment

        self.monthlyPayment.set(self.monthlyPayment)
        self.totalPayment.set(self.totalPayment)


loan1 = Loan()
```

[image]

I added a frame for all the entrys so they all group together

Comment: This code did not give me the expected GUI I needed.

Comment: what about now??

Answer (score 1):

You should try packing your widgets with [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) function...it's a lot more flexible for positioning

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Loan:
    def __init__(self):
        #Create main Window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Loan Calculator")

        #Create the six frames
        self.intRate_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.numYears_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.loanAmount_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.monthlyPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.totalPayment_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # Create and pack the widgets for interest rate
        self.intRate_label = tkinter.Label(self.intRate_frame, \
                text='Annual Interest Rate', anchor="w")
        self.intRate_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.intRate_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.intRate_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.intRate_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        #Create and pack the widgets for number of years
        self.numYears_label = tkinter.Label(self.numYears_frame, \
                text='Number of Years', anchor = "w")
        self.numYears_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.numYears_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.numYears_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.numYears_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)


        #Create and pack the widgets for loan Amount
        self.loanAmount_label = tkinter.Label(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                text='Loan Amount', anchor = "nw")
        self.loanAmount_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.loanAmount_frame, \
                                 width=20)
        self.loanAmount_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.loanAmount_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

        #Create and pack the widgets for monthly payment
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                text='Monthly Payment', anchor="w")
        self.monthlyPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.monthlyPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.monthlyPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.monthlyPayment)
        self.result_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.monthlyPayment_label.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

        #Create and pack the widgets for total payment
        self.result2_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                text='Total Payment', anchor="w")
        self.totalPayment = tkinter.StringVar() # To update avg_label
        self.totalPayment_label = tkinter.Label(self.totalPayment_frame, \
                            textvariable=self.totalPayment)
        self.result2_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.totalPayment_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        #Create and pack the widgets for the button widgets
        self.compute_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                             text='Compute Payment', command=self.calc)
        self.compute_button.pack(side='left')

        self.intRate_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.numYears_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.loanAmount_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.monthlyPayment_frame.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.totalPayment_frame.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc(self):
        #Get 
        self.intRate = float(self.intRate_entry.get())
        self.numYears = float(self.numYears_entry.get())
        self.loanAmount = float(self.loanAmount_entry.get())
        #Calculations
        monthlyIntRate = self.intRate / 1200
        monthlyPayment = self.loanAmount * monthlyIntRate/(1 - (1 / (1 +     [enter image description here][1]monthlyIntRate) ** (self.numYears * 12))) 
        totalPayment = self.monthlyPayment * self.numYears * 12 #calculates the total payment
        self.monthlyPayment.set(self.monthlyPayment)
        self.totalPayment.set(self.totalPayment)


loan1 = Loan()
```

[image]

Comment: That helped the issue of alignment with the labels, but the entry boxes are still not aligned.

Comment: I posted the full code...its working fine. If you want to position the entries then just change ''self.intRate_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)'' to ''self.intRate_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)''

Comment: or you can even make sticky=W+E

Comment: Still getting the same results... It's like the entry boxes are refusing to line up with one another.

Comment: Try packing entries and labela seperatly